# Internet explorer 8 and jQuery: click() for element with transparent background

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, background, click

In IE8 I have a 100% width + height fixed position div, `#photo-upload`,  with a transparent background, which overlays the entire page. I have a click() function for that div, but in IE8 the click does not fire. Setting the background to a solid color solves the problem.

Does anyone have experience with this bug or have a workaround?

```
        $('#photo-upload').click(function(){
            $('#photo-upload').removeClass('show');
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a colored background and set `filter: alpha(opacity=0); opacity: 0;`

I'd be interested if someone posts exactly why this happens but this is the work-around I've found to work.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uMyXC/

Comment: Jasper, thanks for your answer, but that sets the entire DIV and it's contents to transparent. I just want the background transparent.

Comment: Then you can just use two DIV elements. One for the transparent background that is not opaque, and the other that holds the content and is opaque.

Comment: when you're right, you're right... I ended up going with a transparent  .png and it worked. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Figured I'd add the answer from j-man86's comment on the accepted answer in case someone overlooks it at first like I did.

Use a transparent, repeating, 1px square png (or gif, as long as it's fully transparent) as the background image of the overlayed div.

Excellent discovery! Thanks, j-man86!

Comment: This turned out to be the only good solution for this problem. I also had to use the 1x1px PNG image. So much for elegant CSS...

Answer (score 0):

I have only tested this on IE10, but there seems to be a simpler solution with alpha but without filters. Just setting a color with an explicit alpha component of zero seems to do the trick as well:

```
backgroundColor: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the short and sweet way to solve that problem:

```
element{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.01);
}
```

and Done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set a background colour with zero opacity:

```
#photo-upload { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0); }
```

This works on IE9.